# Filtering on multiple fields from deep nested object

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a complicated object that looks something like this:

```
{
  "_type":  "_doc",
  "_id":    "13",
  "name": "X",
  "unitWorkJobRiskWorkingSituations": [
    {
      unitWork: {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "home",
        "priority": 1
      },
      job: {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "developper",
        "priority": 2
      }
    },
    {
      unitWork: {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "home2",
        "priority": 1
      },
      job: {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "developer2",
        "priority": 2
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I want to filter my documents, and return only those how have at least one "unitWorkJobRiskWorkingSituation" object that contain both unitWork with "home" name and a job name "developer"

This is my current query, that does not unfortunately work :

```
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "must":[
        {
          "nested":{
            "path":"unitWorkJobRiskWorkingSituations",
            "query":{
              "bool":{
                "must":[
                  {
                    "terms":{
                      "unitWorkJobRiskWorkingSituations.job.name":["developper"]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "terms":{
                      "unitWorkJobRiskWorkingSituations.unitWork.name":["home"]
                    }
                  }]
              }
            }
          }
        }]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "unitWorkJobRiskWorkingSituations",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "unitWorkJobRiskWorkingSituations.job.name.keyword": [
                        "developper"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "unitWorkJobRiskWorkingSituations",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "unitWorkJobRiskWorkingSituations.unitWork.name.keyword": [
                        "home"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for you hlep, but sorry you answer didnt work !

Comment: Strange, creating docs with developer and home items, and getting docs where the two appear together at least once.
Could you give a better example? Provide data and the mapping.